# Associating Directshape with Level Revit API

Tags: c#, revit-api, revit

Is it possible to associate directshape element with level?
I've tried to manually insert it by parameter, but there is no level parameter in parameters, and setting level directly doesn't work because its a read only. Is there any other way that I can achieve this? Ideally I would like to be able to associate the created directshape into a level, if it is not possible, a string textfield would also do.

```
DirectShape ds = DirectShape.CreateElement(doc, new ElementId(BuiltInCategory.OST_GenericModel));
ds.SetShape(brepBuilder);
ds.LookupParameter("Level").Set(levelID); //<- any alternative....?
ds.LevelId = levelID; // <- this also didnt work.
```

Answer (score 0):

Afaik, the `Level` property can only be set during the creation of an element, e.g., in the [`Wall.Create` method taking a level id argument](https://apidocs.co/apps/revit/2019/0ce4c555-4cee-f5fd-2e84-43cacf34ac5c.htm).

Comment: I thought DirectShape.CreateElement doesnt allow me to set the level property during it's creation?

Comment: _Some_ elements allow you to set a level. Direct shape does not. So I do not see any possibility to set it at all. Sorry.